# How to make JAXB parse scientific notation for BigInteger?

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, schema

I'm kind of a novice when it comes to JAXB and marhsalling/unmarshalling and have been struggling through my implementation to get things working.

So far, I've written my XSDs and generated my POJOs using xjc.  All that works fine.  Additionally, when I need to unmarshall data coming in as String data or a w3c document, I use [JAXBContext.generateSchema()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#generateSchema%28javax.xml.bind.SchemaOutputResolver%29) to produce the matching schema relating to the expected class that I am receiving.  All that works fine as well.

My problem comes when I analyze the schema that generateSchema() produces.  As per the [JAXB docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/webserv/data_types.html#wp231439), a BigDecimal is generated as an xsd decimal type.

My input sometimes contains scientific notation (ex: 1.12E12).  When I try to unmarshall that with the schema generated by JAXB, I get an javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException exception:

```
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '1.32400146520976E-4' is not a valid value for 'decimal'.]
```

Is there some way to properly parse scientific notation when using a "decimal" type or must it be "double"?

Originally, I thought I could use a double representation as double's can parse scientific notation, however, I am dealing with financial values (this is for banking calculations) and consequently, I realized that using a double representation will cause rounding errors due to it's inherent limitations.

So I guess the question becomes how to create custom bindings that would allow me to parse scientific notation and store the data in BigDecimal?  I've looked at [`XMLAdpater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html), but I do not understand how to use it for the case I'm looking at.  If anyone can provide insight or an example (other than the ubiquitous Map example I keep finding online) I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Without custom bindings, NO, since the XML Schema spec is pretty clear on what the [lexical representation of a decimal](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#decimal) is.

2) I would think customization is the only way to overcome this; [another way maybe](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Using_different_datatypes.html)?

What I would be concerned though is that if someone would be trying to use the generated XSD to validate instance XMLs, that will fail now and then unless you have a schema that allows for both... Although [shunned](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_2_2_10-Defining-a-Type-Union.html), xsd:union might be the only way out (you still have to do a custom binding)...

Comment: I was somewhat expecting as much.  After further reflection, I realized that storing the data internally as a double wouldn't even work, so I definitely need custom work, but not sure exactly what that entails. I *think* it is using XMLAdapter, but not sure.